# SQL: Combining LIKE and IN in SQL , and Showing the Array of LIKE in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, sql-like

Below code works to combine Like and IN. But I need a column in the output with the values that I used for the Like:

```
SELECT file_id
FROM   table1 as t
WHERE  archival_date = '20180108'
WHERE  EXISTS(SELECT *
              FROM   (VALUES ('%portfolo1filename%'),
                             ('%portfolo2filename%'),
                             ('%portfolo3filename%')) Vals(val)
              WHERE  filename LIKE '%' + val + '%')
```

What I need as Output:

```
____________________________
val                  file_ID
____________________________
portfolo1filename     2230
portfolo2filename     2240
portfolo3filename     3345
```

Current code's Output:

```
______________
   file_ID
______________
     2230
     2240
     3345
```

Note: val here contains the list of values (i.e filenames) that I need to search as like

table1 has following entries:

---

```
filename                             file_ID    archival_date 
__________________________________________________________________
Broker1_portfolo1filename             2230         20180108
Broker1_portfolo2filename             2240         20180108
Broker2_portfolo3filename             3345         20180908
Broker2_portfolo2filename             1345         20180904
Broker3_portfolo1filename             3045         20180906
Broker2_portfolo2filename             3355         20180907
Broker2_portfolo3filename             7340         20180901
```

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: please provide sample data and expected result

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: @KeithJohnHutchison: Hardly not, I am just looking to populate filenameIDs in against a filename matching pattern

Comment: @TheImpaler: table1 is the database

Comment: Thanks for the update, please show sample table1 input.

Comment: @KeithJohnHutchison : I have added the current output and the required output

Comment: Cool. Please add schema and sample data sql insert statements to your question. I imagine it'd be easier if you create a temporary table first, populate that, then run the query on that table.

Comment: Also you may want to tag the type of database this is...mySQL?  Oracle?  Microsoft SQL?  Something else entirely?

Comment: @user2366842: Microsoft SQL server management studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to convert your `WHERE EXISTS` clause to an `INNER JOIN`, like :

```
SELECT t1.file_id, vals.val
FROM
    table1 t1
    INNER JOIN  (VALUES ('value1'), ('value2'), ('value3')) Vals(val) 
        ON  t1.column1 LIKE '%' + vals.val + '%'
```

The downside of this approach is that if multiple expression match the value of  `column1` in a given record, you will find two rows in the output. To avoid that, you could for example concatenate all succesfully matched expressions in a single field.

If you are using SQL Server 2017 (your query runs fine on this RDBMS), you can use `STRING_AGG` :

```
SELECT t1.file_id, STRING_AGG(vals.val, ',')
FROM   
    table1 t1
    INNER JOIN  (VALUES ('value1'), ('value2'), ('value3')) Vals(val) 
        ON  t1.column1 LIKE '%' + vals.val + '%' 
GROUP BY t1.file_id
```

Tested in [this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b018a6696daae01dcb1dd18babe65024).

Comment: You code includes % sign in the val  column (referring to the first code that you provided). Could you please tell how to remove that? Output: Val : %portfolo1filename%

Comment: @AnandKC : ok,let me check

Comment: `%` in the output do not come from my query. You just need to remove the `%` from the values that you put in the `VALUES (...)` clause.

Comment: Should be `VALUES ('portfolo1filename'), ('portfolo2filename'), ('portfolo3filename')`

Comment: Welcome @AnandKC

Answer (score 0):

this might help,

```
select  distinct file_id, val
from table1,  VALUES ('%portfolo1filename%'),
                     ('%portfolo2filename%'),
                     ('%portfolo3filename%')) Vals(val)
where column1 like '%' + val + '%'
```

---

working code You can check yourself

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table1](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [column1] [varchar](40) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

insert into table1 values (2230,    'portfolo1filename');
insert into table1 values (2245,    'portfolo2filenamedasdas');
insert into table1 values (2250,    'porto');


select  distinct id, val
from table1, (VALUES ('%portfolo1filename%'),
                     ('%portfolo2filename%'),
                     ('%portfolo3filename%')) Vals(val)
where column1 like '%' + val + '%'
```

[Working Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8393b628717d0d506bdbda97edb72b28)